# iOS 9.2 app runs in background, but didReceiveRemoteNotification doesn't execute when I receive remoteNotification

Tags: ios

Those two API don't get called

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [self handleRemoteNotifications:userInfo];

    [APService handleRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    [self handleRemoteNotifications:userInfo];

    [APService handleRemoteNotification:userInfo];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: i run app connecting with my Mac ,It work well.but when i run without connecting My Mac . i found this problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the app is suspended or killed since it works when connected to a Mac.

You may want to add the remote-notification capability in the background modes to allow iOS to wake the app. Also, iOS may delay waking the app if the app consume too much power during previous awakening.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: had nothing to do with  iOS 9.2 or iOS  9.0 , other factor cause it，thanks